# How to extract AnonymousType Programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to extract AnoymousType, this is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Extract(new { Name = "Yoza" });
    Extract(new [] { new { Name = "Yoza" }, new { Name = "Dhika" } });
}

private static void Extract(object param = null)
{
    if(param.GetType().IsArray)
    {
        // Do something to get everyname
        // Do Something to get value of variable "Name"
    }
    else
    {
        // Do Something to get a name
        // Do Something to get value of variable "Name"
    }
}
```

if i do not place that code in method, it works, like this:

```
        var dd = new { A = "Yoza" };
        var cc = new[] { new { A = "Yoza" } };

        String name = dd.A;
        name = cc[0].A;
```

the problem is I want place it in method.
How to Extract AnonympusType programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optionally you can make a use of Reflection API to get the values from object like below:

```
public class Program 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Extract(new { Name = "Yoza" });
        Extract(new [] { new { Name = "Yoza" }, new { Name = "Dhika" } });
    }

    private static void Extract(object param = null) 
    {
        if (param.GetType().IsArray) 
        {
            var array = param as Array;
            foreach(var element in array) 
            {
                foreach(var item in element.GetType().GetProperties()) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", item.Name, item.GetValue(element)));
                }
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            foreach(var item in param.GetType().GetProperties()) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", item.Name, item.GetValue(param)));
                item.GetValue(param);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e4GJo7) is working DOT NET FIDDLE.

Answer (score 1):

You could accept `dynamic` in `Extract`:

```
static void Extract(dynamic dd)
{
    string name;
    if (dd.GetType().IsArray)
    {
        name = dd[0].Name;
    }
    else
    {
        name = dd.Name;
    }
}
```

Whether or not this is a good idea depends entirely on your use case, which isn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic` as suggested, but split the two cases:

```
private static void Extract<T>(T param)
{
    string name = ((dynamic)param).Name;
}

private static void Extract<T>(T[] param)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
    {
        string name = ((dynamic)param[i]).Name;
    }
}
```

You'll gain a little in speed, because in this way the split of single vs array is done by the compiler.

What **I** would normally do is:

```
private static void Extract<T>(T param, Func<T, string> getName)
{
    string name = getName(param);
}

private static void Extract<T>(T[] param, Func<T, string> getName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
    {
        string name = getName(param[i]);
    }
}
```

Use like:

```
Extract(new { Name = "Yoza" }, x => x.Name);
Extract(new [] { new { Name = "Yoza" }, new { Name = "Dhika" } }, x => x.Name);
```

This will totally remove the dynamic/reflection part and made your code compiler-verified (and wholly strongly typed).

Comment: Those are ambiguous overloads, so you would get a compiler error unless you specify the generic type parameter, which you can't do with an anonymous type.

Comment: I did [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xCqSB2). But I see what the difference is. I was passing null for getName parameter. Which is sort of interesting. The first set of methods compiles fine, no ambiguous overload. But adding another parameter (getName) which in theory shouldn't be necessary to pick the overload and passing a value compatible for both overloads (null) causes an ambiguity error.

Comment: @mikez Yes... that is quite funny (as funny as overload resolution can be)... Fortunately I consider non-basic method resolution to be a black box that you kick until it works, so this night I'll sleep perfectly well :-)... But if you discover why this happens, still I would be interested to know why (one can always sleep perfectly well *plus* :-) )